# Two- phase simplex method problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, two-phase-simplex

I have this problem:

Minimize:

$x_1+3x_2-x_3$

Subject to:

$$
\begin{align}
2x_1+x_2+3x_3 \geq 3\\
-x_1+x_2\geq1\\
-x_1-5x_2+x_3\leq4\\
x_1,x_2,x_3, \geq 0\\
\end{align}$$

I need help solving it though the two phase simplex method. I keep getting stuck and need help determining whether or not it has a feasible region and what the feasible points are. I think I keep cycling the pivots but am not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It might be wrong but I think we cannot minimize $\,x_1+3x_2-x_3\,$

$-----------$

Let $\,x_1=0,\ x_2\geq1,\ x_3=4x_2$, $\ $then we have
$$2x_1+x_2+3x_3=13x_2>3$$
$$-x_1+x_2=x_2\geq1$$
$$-x_1-5x_2+x_3=-x_2<4$$
$$x_1=0,\ \ x_2>0,\ \ x_3=4x_2>0$$
Now all inequalities hold, so we can make $\,x_2\,$be infinitely large, and that will make $$\,x_1+3x_2-x_3=-x_2\,$$
be infinitely small.

As a result, we cannot minimize $$\,x_1+3x_2-x_3\,$$ because there is no such a minimum value.